tactic 'rewrite' failed, pattern is a metavariable
example {p q : Prop} (H: p) : ¬ ¬ p := by
  rewrite [←Classical.not_not] at H

Error:
tactic 'rewrite' failed, pattern is a metavariable
  ?m.16
from equation
  ?m.16 = ¬¬?m.16
p q : Prop
H : p
⊢ ¬¬p

How to fix the error and rewrite from right to left?

Seems to work if you pass the argument explicitly like rewrite [←@Classical.not_not p] at H.
